# LocalBroadcastManager onReceive() not called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

This is what I'm doing :

I'm sending an intent from `MainActvity` to my `Fragment` using `LocalBroadcastManager`. I wrote the `onReceive()` code in `onCreateView()` of the Fragment class. I'm unregistering the Receiver in `onDestroy()`.

But `onReceive()` is not getting called. Why?

In **MainActivity** class :

```
   void handleText()
{ 
          Intent i = new Intent("receiveURL");
          i.putExtra("key", sharedText);

          this.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

In my **Fragment** class :

```
public class AddTab extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    BroadcastReceiver  receiver;

    EditText textBox;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

        textBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
//This is not getting called
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String g = intent.getStringExtra("key");
                textBox = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
                if (textBox != null){
                    textBox.setText(g);}
                else{
                    Log.d("NULL", "");
                }

                Log.d("received","");
                }
            };

      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("receiveURL"));
...
//some code
    }


    public void onDestroy() {


         super.onDestroy();
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

}
```

Why is that receiver is not getting called? Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this.sendBroadcast(i)` which sends a *global*, inter-app broadcast that will not be received by a `LocalBroadcastManager`.

In your `MainActivity`, replace

```
this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

with

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
```

This will work.

Comment: I'm getting this : Non-static method sendBroadcast() cannot be accessed from a static context.

Comment: One minute please, emulator is loading.

Comment: I know this is out of context of this question. But one thing - I'm able to get into onReceive() method. But textBox.setText() isn't working.  Does setText () work in a Fragment? I mean should I attach and detach the fragment? I cannot see populated textBox. Any help @ZygoteInit?

Comment: @nikhil: how about posting this as a new question, and then give me the link here ? :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue resolved on removing the receiver unregister() from onPause().